# Set the Enabled Property of a UserControl From CodeBehind

Tags: asp.net, webforms, c#-3.0

It's been a while since I worked on WebForms so I need a refresher when working on an old site.

I have a userControl on the page that I need to programatically set the enabled state

```
<%@ Register Src="CalandarControl.ascx" TagName="CalandarControl" TagPrefix="uc" %>
```

I have this at the C# code but Enabled is not available here. What am I missing?

```
if (c is UserControl)
{
    var x = c.GetType();
    if (x.Name == "calendarcontrol_ascx")
    {
        ((UserControl)c).Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `Enabled` is [not a property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.UserControl_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) of `UserControl`. What are you trying to do? Also, in your code snippet you are using `c` but then end up casting `control` as a `UserControl`.

Comment: Hey Mike I'm trying to set the control enabled if the user is in a particular role. Currently they have the control enabled property set on the aspx page at the control level                 <uc:CalendarControl ID="dtePrepaymentExpiresDate" FieldName="Prepayment expires date" runat="server" Enabled="false" />.

The 'control' was a typeo from previous code attempts. it's actually c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have something on the code-front that places the control on the page, like:

```
<uc:CalendarControl ID="dtePrepaymentExpiresDate" FieldName="Prepayment expires date" runat="server" Enabled="false" />
```

Then in the code behind, you can set this custom property as follows:

```
dtePrepaymentExpiresDate.Enabled = true;
```

If you really need to do it in the loop, then you need to cast `c` as the `CalendarControl` and not `UserControl` because `CalendarControl` has the property `Enabled` while a normal `UserControl` does not.

```
((CalandarControl)c).Enabled = true;
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. I tried using CalandarControl prior to UserControl and it couldn't find the reference. The Control had the Enabled Property already it turns out that I don't know how to spell CalendarControl correctly. Dooh. This was a good answer thanks again.

Comment: Or if you are just setting it to a role... skip the loop and the `if` statement and just do something like `dtePrepaymentExpiresDate.Enabled = User.IsInRole("bigAdmin");` And yeah I noticed the typo in control name too ;)

Comment: There are several CalendarControls on the page and they are all bound by the same role logic so I find it easier to run generics as much as possible

Answer (score 1):

you can define a panel in usercontrol witch cotaines all of controls of the user control, then define a property Enabled named as bool (panelMain.Enabled;) and from ur page set it,

in user control ascx

```
<asp:panel runat="server" id="panelMain" Enabled="false">

<!-- define ur other controls between panel-->

</asp:panel>
```

in usercontrol ascx.cs

```
public bool Enabled
{
    get { return panelMain.Enabled;  }
    set { panelMain.Enabled = value; }
}
```

in page first register ur usercontrol and then set Enabled property from code behind ....
for example

```
 protected void Page_load(object sender,EventArgs e )
 {
     panelMain.Enabled = true;
 }
```

as simple as drink water :))

Comment: I think you purposed to have **public bool Enabled** typed as:
get { return panelMain.Enabled;}
set { panel.Enabled = value; }